# how to Send Photo take from Esp32-cam by Telegram

Tags: image-processing, arduino, camera, telegram, esp32

```
#include "esp_camera.h"  
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
```

How to Convert from:

```
 fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
```

by something accepted by   Telegram

e.g.

> String sent = bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, ....

or

> String sent = bot.sendPhotoByBinary(chat_id, ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save the image to SD card and then send photo using the bot api.
See more:
[save to sd card](https://github.com/raphaelbs/esp32-cam-ai-thinker/blob/master/examples/sd_jpg/main/main.c),
[send photo](https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot/blob/master/examples/ESP8266/SendPhoto/PhotoFromSD/PhotoFromSD.ino).